# Defining own main functions arguments argc and argv

Tags: c++, qt

i want to create an object of type QApplication which needs the main functions arguments argc and argv as an input:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

Since i am within a user defined function without access to the main function i want to define this arguments on my own. I have tried several approaches but i cannot get the type conversion right. My last approach did not work either:

```
int argc = 1;
char **argv; 
char arguments[1][12] = {{"cgalExample"}};
argv = arguments;
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Could you please clarify what didn't work? Didn't compile? error executing? not doing what you expected?

Comment: Compiler error under Visual Studio 2008: Unable to convert the types. Hint of gs worked fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but working for `QApplication`:

```
char *argv[] = {"program name", "arg1", "arg2", NULL};
int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(char*) - 1;
```

**For a more complete and C standard conforming solution see [D.Shawley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519885/c-c-defining-own-main-functions-arguments-argc-and-argv/1519997#1519997).**

Why your solution doesn't work is simple:

`array[i][j]` results in a `i*j` matrix. But what you actually want is an array with pointers to strings in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one compiles under VS 2008.

Comment: Might want to mention that the first argument is the program name.

Comment: Nice correction for program name and NULL, but char* still should point to mutable strings... literal strings are not.

Comment: Havoc is likely to be wrought if argv[argc] != NULL; code is supposed to be able to rely on that.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to be insanely pendantic, then you want something like the following.  The key points are that `argv` is not `const`, `argv` is `NULL` terminated, `argc` is the number of usable elements in `argv` **including the program name**.  It is required to be modifiable so you cannot use string literals - `argv[i]` is required to point to a modifiable array of characters.

```
int my_main() {
    char  arg0[] = "programName";
    char  arg1[] = "arg";
    char  arg2[] = "another arg";
    char* argv[] = { &arg0[0], &arg1[0], &arg2[0], NULL };
    int   argc   = (int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;

    QApplication the_application(argc, &argv[0]);
    return the_application.run();
}
```

The Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.1) states that the following is true about `argc` and `argv` in a hosted environment:

- The value of **`argc`** shall be nonnegative.
- **`argv[argc]`** shall be a null pointer.
- If the value of **`argc`** is greater than zero, the array members **`argv[0]`** through **`argv[argc-1]`** inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment.  If the host environment is not capable of supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
- If the value of **`argc`** is greater than zero, the string pointed to by **`argv[0]`** represents the *program name*; **`argv[0][0]`** shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment.  If the value of **`argc`** is greater than one, the strings pointed to by **`argv[0]`** through **`argv[argc-1]`** represent *program parameters*.
- The parameters **`argc`** and **`argv`** and the strings pointed to by the **`argv`** array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

[`QApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) states the following:

> **Warning:** The data referred to by `argc` and `argv` must stay valid for the
>   entire lifetime of the `QApplication`
>   object. In addition, `argc` must be
>   greater than zero and `argv` must
>   contain at least one valid character
>   string.
>
> …
>
> Note: `argc` and `argv` might be changed
>   as Qt removes command line arguments
>   that it recognizes.

Comment: Just one question, should it not be (int)((sizeof ...) - 1)?  Otherwise argc[argv] will point one past the NULL...

Comment: @gimpf: just noticed that myself. Thanks.

Comment: @alex tingle: take a look at clause 14 of section 6.7.8 of C99 or clause 1 of section 8.5.2 in C++98. Both clearly state that _a `char` array can be initialized from a string-literal (optionally enclosed in braces); successive characters of the string-literal initialize the members of the array._

Comment: Isn't `&arg0[0]` the same as just `arg0`?

Comment: @gs: it's true in most cases.  C++ will choose a template specialization like `template <typename T, size_t N> void foo(T (&ary)[N])` over `template <typename T> void foo(T val)` if such a specialization exists. The type if `arg0` matches `char (&)[12]` before it will degrade to `char*`.  I just got into the habit of passing either `char*` or a reference to an array explicitly.

Comment: Your answer is THE correct version for me. I'm passing some args to a main-method which calls `strsep` on that arguments. If I use another way than yours, eg. Shaley's, then eg. `strsep` fails with a SEGFAULT (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972332/strsep-segmentation-faults-on-different-string-pointer-array-types).

Comment: The `QApplication` docs don't actually say whether `argv[argc]` must be null; I agree to err on the side of caution and give it the same guarantees as `main()`.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you concerning your self with the size of the text in argv, I would just let the compiler do it:

```
int argc = 1;
char* argv[] = {"Hello Qt!"}; // exactly as it is defined in main
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't compile for one thing: "error: brace-enclosed initializer used to initialize ‘char*’"

Comment: @alex It compiles fine with me (VC2008). What compiler are you using?

Comment: Yes, but isn't it required that the argv array itself is null-terminated?

Comment: Yes, I know about `argc`, but if you spawn a process in linux, not doing so will result in a segfault; and if you search on google, there are some security notes on this.

Comment: @gimpf argc holds the number of arguments in argv.

Comment: gcc 4.0.1: `warning: braces around scalar initializer`

Comment: @gimpf Honestly, I have no idea about programming in Linux. Isn't argc required by C/C++ standards to hold the number of arguments?

Comment: I tried this one too and i get the following compiler error:

Error 4error C2664: 'QApplication::QApplication(int &,char **,int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'char **'

Comment: @gs I tied it using VC2008 (/W4) and it doesn't give me any warning!

Comment: I did a search on this: "The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.", see: http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec
Yes, argc must hold the number, but it seems somebody wanted to allow for the `while(++argv)` style.

Comment: @gimpf, this is a completely different problem. The `execl` function takes null-terminated arguments. `argv` itself isn't null-terminated.

Comment: @gs I removed the braces around the text just because I trust GCC ;)

Comment: @gs: the Standard requires that `argv` is `NULL` terminated. See my answer for the exact text.

Comment: AraK: Here's 10p, get yourself a proper compiler :)

Comment: @D.Shawley: Thanks! That's really interesting.

Answer (score 3):

How about...

```
int argc = 2;
const char* argv[] ={"program","first-argument"};
```

...or if you need them to be non-const...

```
int argc = 2;
char* argv[] ={strdup("program"),strdup("first-argument")};
```

Comment: Don't forget about calling `free(ptr)` if you ever use this.

Answer (score 0):

Although neither the C nor C++ standard requires it, most compilers make the arguments to main available to you as _argv and _argc. If memory serves POSIX requires this. Anyway, you need to use something like:

```
extern int _argc;
extern char *_argv[];
```

and from there you can use them about like normal.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this works:

```
char* argv[1];
argv[0] = "cgalExample";
```

Comment: You are initialising char* with a const char[]. Naughty!