# strsep segmentation faults on different string pointer/array types

Tags: c, string, memory-management, libc

Platform: Linux, OSX
Compiler: GCC

I've got a simple program which is currently confounding me - I know that I'm messing with a couple different kinds of arrays/pointers to produce this problem - its intentional - I'm trying to understand it.

The code as listed will compile and run as expected, but changing `data4` in the call to `strsep(&data4, "e");` to `data1` or `data3` causes a segmentation fault. I would like to understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int c, char** v) {
    char* data1 = "hello\0";
    char* data2 = strdup(data1);
    size_t sz = strlen(data1);
    char data3[sz+1];
    char* data4;

    memset(data3, 0, sz+1);
    data4 = strncpy(data3, data1, sz);
    data4[sz] = '\0';

    char* found = strsep(&data4, "e");

    if (found == NULL) {
        printf("nothing found\n");
    } else {
        printf("found e\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> changing data4 in the call to strsep(&data4, "e"); to data1 or data3 causes a segmentation fault.

In this case:

```
char* found = strsep(&data1, "e");
```

the string pointed to by `data1` is a literal so it cannot be changed. When `strsep()` tries to place a '\0' into it, segfault.

in the other case:

```
char* found = strsep(&data3, "e");
```

`data3` is an array, not a pointer (even though arrays easily evaluate to pointers, they are not actually pointers), so `strsep()` cannot update the value of the pointer which is what it tries to do once it finds the token. I get the following warning from gcc attempting to point this out:

```
test.c:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strsep' from incompatible pointer type
```