# Test function that depends on QApplication with gmock

Tags: c++, qt, googlemock

I want to test a method which gets the screen size of the primary screen using

```
void MouseMapper::getScreenProperties() {
    QDesktopWidget *widget = QApplication::desktop();
    QRect screenGeometry = widget->screenGeometry(widget->primaryScreen());
    _screenHeight = screenGeometry.height();
    _screenWidth = screenGeometry.width();
}
```

This works properly. But when I try to test it using gmock with

```
TEST(AMouseMapper, GetsTheScreenSize) {
    MouseMapper mouse;
    mouse.getScreenProperties();
    //I know these hardcodes values don't always apply,
    //thats not the point here
    ASSERT_EQ(1900, mouse.getScreenWidth());
    ASSERT_EQ(1200, mouse.getScreenHeight());
}
```

and

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I get an error, because I didn't construct a QApplication, which is correct.
So when I try

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    app.exec();
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I get the same error. It also occurs when I try to construct the QApplication directly in the  test function (as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519885/defining-own-main-functions-arguments-argc-and-argv)) that the test crashes, because argc and argv are either not correct or whatever

```
TEST(AMouseMapper, GetsTheScreenSize) {
    char  arg0[] = "programName";
    char* argv[] = { &arg0[0], NULL };
    int   argc   = (int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;
    QApplication app(argc,&argv[0]);
    app.exec();
    MouseMapper mouse;
    mouse.getScreenProperties();
    ASSERT_EQ(1900, mouse.getScreenWidth()); //I know that these hardcoded values don't always apply
    ASSERT_EQ(1200, mouse.getScreenHeight());
}
```

Valgrind then gives me

```
==7093== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7093==    at 0x102E437A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.25)
==7093==    by 0x7EA2473: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4200.0)
==7093==    by 0x7EBC056: g_signal_emit_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4200.0)
==7093==    by 0x7EBCEF9: g_signal_emit_by_name (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4200.0)
==7093==    by 0x7EA9BDA: g_object_set_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4200.0)
==7093==    by 0x7EAA46B: g_object_set (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4200.0)
==7093==    by 0x5EB0BB5: ??? (in /home/elmewo/Libraries/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.3.2)
==7093==    by 0x5E2D23E: QStyleFactory::create(QString const&) (in /home/elmewo/Libraries/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.3.2)
==7093==    by 0x5DC9B4A: QApplication::style() (in /home/elmewo/Libraries/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.3.2)
==7093==    by 0x5DCA51C: QApplicationPrivate::initialize() (in /home/elmewo/Libraries/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.3.2)
==7093==    by 0x5DCA56F: QApplicationPrivate::construct() (in /home/elmewo/Libraries/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.3.2)
==7093==    by 0x47B10E: AMouseMapper_GetsTheScreenSize_Test::TestBody() (MouseMapperTest.cpp:18)
```

I have no idea what I can do here. Can anyone help?

P.s.: I do not want to use QTest here. :)

Answer (score 0):

We use the following approach:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TestCoreApp app(argc, argv);
    ...
    app.exec();
}
```

In the Constructor of TestCoreApp:

```
TestCoreApp::TestCoreApp(int& argc, char** argv)
    : QCoreApplication(argc, argv)
{
    InitGMockAndGTest(argc, argv);
}
```

Init Function:

```
void TestCoreApp::InitGMockAndGTest(int& argc, char** argv) const
{
    InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
}
```

Your GoogleMockInit starts before QCoreApplication is initialized.

```
testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
QApplication app(argc,argv);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. Just for clarification: TestCoreApp is a class which inherits from QCoreApplication. What is QIWMTestCoreApp?

Comment: Yes TestCoreApp  inherits from QCoreApplication. And QIWMT... was a copy paste mistake.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The error remains the same.